# diff command not working inside bash shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, diff, tar

I am trying to run

```
diff <(tar -tvf HIVE_CLIENT.tar.gz | sort) <(tar -tvf YARN_CLIENT.tar.gz | sort)
```

putting this command inside script, when I execute script it shows error

```
syntax error near unexpected token `(' "
```

But when I do not put inside script rather than run from shell directly it works.

Comment: Show shebang of your script and how do you run this script.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your script is run with `/bin/sh` and not with `/bin/bash`, but command substitution is a bash feature and not implemented in sh. So I suppose you are using bash as your shell which is why it is working from the command line.

Try adding this prefix to your script, and remove existing shebangs (like `#!/bin/sh` or similar):

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 1):

You should try following two actions:

1. Use `#!/bin/bash` as your shebang (First line of your script)
2. This may be needed based on your `bash`, use only if opetion 1 does not help. Use following commands to flip between `posix` mode which is needed for process substitution:

   ```
   set +o posix 
   diff <(tar -tvf HIVE_CLIENT.tar.gz | sort) <(tar -tvf YARN_CLIENT.tar.gz | sort)
   set -o posix
   ```

   Example:

   ```
   wc -l <(ls -lrt)
   sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('

   set +o posix  
   wc -l <(ls -lrt)
   114 /dev/fd/00

   set -o posix
   wc -l <(ls -lrt)
   sh: syntax error near unexpected token `('
   ```